# Select Display no Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, display

Tenho um select com UF´s e outra com Cidades em meu código. Quando troco de UF as cidades são carregadas em outro select. Faço isso por meio do display block e display none, em cima de um conjunto de cidades, quando a sigla da UF da cidade é igual a sigla da UF do select, dou um display block, se não, uso display none.

O nome da cidade no select, que possui todas as cidades, está dividido com um ponto, que separa o nome com a sigla da UF, dessa forma: "Vitoria.ES".

Exemplo:

```
comboCidade = function(){

var comboCidade = document.getElementById('cidade');
comboCidade.options[0].selected = "true";
for (i = 0; i < comboCidade.length; i++) {
    var valor = comboCidade.options[i].value;
    var sigla = valor.split(".");

    if ($("#uf").val() == sigla[1]) {
        comboCidade.options[i].style.display = "block";
    }else{
        comboCidade.options[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}}
```

Dessa forma ele funciona normalmente para alguns estados, mas quando seleciono outros estados, o select simplesmente não mostra o conteúdo, apesar de ele esta lá, pois se eu apertar a seta para baixo, eu consigo navegar pela opções e após eu fazer isso, ai sim o select mostra os valores dele.

Gostaria de saber se isso é um bug do Chrome, pois no firefox funciona perfeitamente, ou se é erro no código.

edit: html do preenchimento das combo box

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Cidade:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="cidade" name="cidade" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <?php
                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM cidade";
                       $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sae;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                       $consulta = $pdo->query($sql);
                       $listarUf = $consulta->fetchAll();
                foreach($listarUf as $dado){
                //foreach ($Conn->query($sql) as $dados) {?>
                    <option value=<?php echo $dado['nome_cidade'].".".$dado['sigla_uf'];?> > <?php echo $dado['nome_cidade']; ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">UF:</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
              <select id="uf" name="uf" class="form-control" onchange="comboCidade()">
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                  <?php
                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM uf";
                         $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sae;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                         $consulta = $pdo->query($sql);
                         $listarUf = $consulta->fetchAll();
                  foreach($listarUf as $dado){
                  //foreach ($Conn->query($sql) as $dados) {?>
                      <option value=<?php echo $dado['sigla_uf'];?> > <?php echo $dado['nome_uf']; ?> </option>
                  <?php } ?>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Você pode postar o seu HTML?

Comment: Acredito que seja apenas um problema de lógica no seu código. Uma vez que você "retira" o estado da lista, quando ele volta a ser visível?

Comment: Essa função esta associada ao onchange do combo box UF, toda vez que troco de estado essa função é chamada, dessa forma, ele compara o estado da cidade com o do combo box, se for igual ele exibe a cidade novamente.